# Can I charge a 12 Volt 2 Ampere UPS with a 9 Volt 0.6 Ampere Adapter?

Tags: battery

I want to power up an Arduino toy car with this UPS but I am not sure if I can charge this UPS with a 9 Volt 0.6 Ampere power adapter.

[image: UPS]

[image: Power Adapter]

Answer (score 2):

The miniUPS clearly states that it takes an input of 12 V and a current greater than 1 A.

The voltage of the input is the most important. Using a 9 V supply will probably not supply sufficient *voltage* to charge the miniUPS, which is 12 V - so there is a deficit of 3V.

The current of the power supply isn't such a major issue: if the *current* is lower than specified to be required, then charging will probably just take (much) longer.

That said, plug it in and see if it charges. It probably will not, but try it and see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Please don't forget to take the [tour]. Also upvote and/or mark the answer as the accepted answer, if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, mabye not. Depending on how the 9V adapter is created it could sense a 1A draw as a short circuit and could brownout or otherwise turn off for short-circuit protection. But regardless, it'll never work with the voltages incorrect.